# MS Access: Custom crosstab query row sorting

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is my crosstab query. I would like to order it with a particular VENDOR_NAME first and then have the rest be alphabetical. I have accomplished this in many other (non-crosstab) queries throughout my project using:

```
ORDER BY iif(VENDOR_NAME = 'GNC',0,1), VENDOR_NAME ASC, ITEM_NO
```

When I try to toss this into the crosstab query I am told that the iif statement conflicts with the GROUP BY clause. Is there any way around this? Full crosstab code below.

```
PARAMETERS Forms!frm_PSFViewer!cmb_TDNo Long;
TRANSFORM Sum(PREKIT_CONTENTS.ITEM_QTY) AS SumOfITEM_QTY
SELECT 
PSF_ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_KEY
,VENDORS.VENDOR_NAME
,ITEMS.ITEM_NO
FROM VENDORS 
INNER JOIN (PREKITS 
INNER JOIN ((ITEMS 
INNER JOIN PREKIT_CONTENTS 
   ON ITEMS.ITEM_ID = PREKIT_CONTENTS.ITEM_KEY) 
INNER JOIN PSF_ITEM_DETAILS 
   ON ITEMS.ITEM_ID = PSF_ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_KEY) 
   ON PREKITS.PREKIT_ID = PREKIT_CONTENTS.PREK_KEY) 
   ON VENDORS.VENDOR_ID = PSF_ITEM_DETAILS.PRNT_VEND_KEY
WHERE ((([PREKITS].[PSF_KEY])=[Forms]![frm_PSFViewer]![cmb_TDNo]) 
   AND ((PREKITS.PREKIT)<>'ARCHWAY'))
GROUP BY PSF_ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_KEY, VENDORS.VENDOR_NAME, ITEMS.ITEM_NO
ORDER BY VENDORS.VENDOR_NAME, ITEMS.ITEM_NO
PIVOT PREKIT_CONTENTS.PREK_KEY;
```

Comment: Try putting Vendor_Name as first field in the SELECT.

Comment: This appears to result in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it by adding that iif into the GROUP BY clause.

```
PARAMETERS Forms!frm_PSFViewer!cmb_TDNo Long;
TRANSFORM Sum(PREKIT_CONTENTS.ITEM_QTY) AS SumOfITEM_QTY
SELECT 
PSF_ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_KEY
,VENDORS.VENDOR_NAME
,ITEMS.ITEM_NO
FROM VENDORS 
INNER JOIN (PREKITS 
INNER JOIN ((ITEMS 
INNER JOIN PREKIT_CONTENTS 
   ON ITEMS.ITEM_ID = PREKIT_CONTENTS.ITEM_KEY) 
INNER JOIN PSF_ITEM_DETAILS 
   ON ITEMS.ITEM_ID = PSF_ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_KEY) 
   ON PREKITS.PREKIT_ID = PREKIT_CONTENTS.PREK_KEY) 
   ON VENDORS.VENDOR_ID = PSF_ITEM_DETAILS.PRNT_VEND_KEY
WHERE ((([PREKITS].[PSF_KEY])=[Forms]![frm_PSFViewer]![cmb_TDNo]) 
   AND ((PREKITS.PREKIT)<>'ARCHWAY'))
GROUP BY PSF_ITEM_DETAILS.ITEM_KEY, iif(VENDOR_NAME = 'GNC',0,1), VENDOR_NAME, ITEMS.ITEM_NO
ORDER BY iif(VENDOR_NAME = 'GNC',0,1), ITEMS.ITEM_NO
PIVOT PREKIT_CONTENTS.PREK_KEY;
```